# Inserting values from multiple select drop downs with same name

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have several select menus that all have the same name, mainly because I want them to insert them into the same database column.

My lists look like this.

```
<span id="books">
 <label>Book:&nbsp;</label>
 <select class="drop"  name="fanCat">
  <option value="">Select One</option>
  <?foreach($ficBook as $row) :?>
    <option value="<?=$row->fic_name?>"><?=$row->fic_name?></option>
  <?endforeach;?>
 </select>
</span>
```

Now I know I could loop through and array and populate them into the database and I have tried to do that, but in my jQuery I have it so that only one of these select menus are viewable at a time (based on a pre-selected value). Thus looping though each value is impossible and I don't really want multiple values being selected anyways. Just the select drop down that the user sees.

The PHP in my model looks like this:

```
$this->fanfictionCategory = $this->input->post('fanCat');
$this->db->insert('story_tbl', $this);
```

It is supposed to be inserting into a column that is a `varchar`. Originally I had it as an `enum` with all the values listed because I thought it would be easier, but that proved wrong.

How can I make this work?.

Comment: Same name different id `<select class="drop"  name="fanCat" id = "1">`  `<select class="drop"  name="fanCat" id = "2">`

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work.... I'm not using id's for anything other than style and I have those are on the span outside the actual select tag.

Comment: I want something similar but I use form_multiselect. I am still figuring out how to do this. I am able to insert/update 1 'category' at a time. But with multiselect I'd like to insert/update 3 'categories'

Comment: I could not figure this out and ended up creating separate columns in my database for each select menu. I hope you have better luck!